# ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'created_date'; check that column/key exists

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
mysql> alter table bill_item add  index idx_comp(created_date,product_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (1 min 2.62 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1
```

Trying to drop the index:

```
mysql> alter table bill_item drop index created_date;
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'created_date'; check that column/key exists
```

Comment: Hi, First of all, welcome to the site. There are a few problems with your question preventing answers. Please show all the code and table definitions and sample data. Please do the [tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) read through the [help section](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how this site works. especially how to [ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You will attract more answers and useful feedback.

Comment: You're confusing index name and column name. When you want to drop an index, use the index name.

Comment: The error mean that: **You are trying to drop an index that doesn't exists. Check the column/key if that exists. .**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to drop the index that you created previously, the correct statement would be:

`alter table bill_item drop index idx_comp;`

`created_date` is the name of one of the columns in your table `bill_item`.

Note: To find the index name use 
`SHOW INDEXES FROM <table>` if you used a different naming convention than prepending 'idx_'

Comment: its not working same above.... alter table bill_item drop index idx_comp;.... error only ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'created_date'; check that column/key exists